# How to autoFocus on list item after deleting an item?

Tags: reactjs, autofocus

I have [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hlwqpg?file=index.js) react code on **Stackblitz** where `autoFocus` works when a new item is added to the list but the same doesn't work when an item is deleted.

I need to find a solution where the last item remains in autoFocus when any item is deleted from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array of refs to manage your inputs :

```js
import React, { Component, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <InputList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function InputList() {
  const refs = React.useRef([]);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const add = useCallback(() => setItems([...items, {id: '1'}]), [items]);
  const ondelete = useCallback(() => {
    const index = items.length -1;

    if (index - 1 >= 0) {
      refs.current[index - 1].focus();
    } 

    setItems(items.splice(1));
  });


  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item,i) => <input ref={e => refs.current[i] = e} key={item.i} autoFocus={i === items.length - 1 ? true : false}/>)}
      <button onClick={add} type="button">Add</button>
      <button onClick={ondelete} type="button">Delete</button>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I added the array of refs and modified your `onDelete` method to focus the correct input.

Comment: I just want to add a comment for Material UI TextField component. Quentin's solutions works like a charm for simple input components but for MUI TextField we need to the add the ref to 'inputRef' attribute like ```inputRef={e => refs.current[i]}```